# ObservableCollection doesn't reflect changes for Summary calculation

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a `DataGrid` backed with a manually handled `ObservableCollection<T>` in code behind. When I add a new item to the backed list or delete one, the `Count` is updated but the `ItemsSource` is not notified so that the sum of `Price` updates. I even tried `BindingList<T>` but even the `Count` stopped updating! What's the hack?

XAML:

```
<Label>
   <Label.Content>
        <TextBlock>
             <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Count: {0}, Sum: {1}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True">
                    <Binding ElementName="datagrid" Path="ItemsSource.Count" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="datagrid" Path="ItemsSource" Converter="{StaticResource SumConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

SumConverter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableCollection<DocView>), typeof(String))]
public class SumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is ObservableCollection<DocView>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<DocView> items = (ObservableCollection<DocView>)value;
            return items.Sum(x => x.Price);
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Code behind:

```
ObservableCollection<DocView> list = new ObservableCollection<DocView>();

datagrid.DataContext = list;
```

Comment: Make sure your properties implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the way you bind the list to the `datagrid` and that the converter doesn't pick up changes in the `ItemSource` as that property doesn't change. The collection doesn't trigger the `PropertyChanged` event. Try this:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

And in your XAML use the converter on the multi binding. The binding to `ItemsSource.Count` will trigger notification when the collection changes. Note you don't need to embed the `TextBlock` in a `Label`.

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SumConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="datagrid" Path="ItemsSource" />
                <Binding ElementName="datagrid" Path="ItemsSource.Count"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Obviously you need to amend your converter accordingly.

```
 public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values != null && values.Length > 0 && values[0] is ObservableCollection<string>)
            {
                ObservableCollection<DocView> items = (ObservableCollection<DocView>)values[0];
                return string.Format("Count: {0}, Sum: {1}", items.Count, items.Sum(x => x.Price));
            }
            else
                return "Count: 0, Sum: 0";
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

This is a solution requiring the least changes. Better it would be to bind the collection to the ViewModel and not to the `datagrid.ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution:

1. Wrap everything in a view model and implement `INPC` every where
2. Use `BindingList<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>` (If you use `ObservableCollection<T>` the updates to properties of existing items in list won't trigger the updates to UI while `BindingList<T>` supports this)

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" />

    <Label>
       <Label.Content>
            <TextBlock>
                 <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Count: {0}, Sum: {1}" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True">
                         <Binding ElementName="datagrid" Path="DataContext.Count"/>
                         <Binding ElementName="datagrid" Path="DataContext.Total"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Code behind:

```
DocViewModel list= new DocViewModel();
datagrid.DataContext = list;
```

**DocViewModel**:

```
public class DocViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DocViewModel()
    {
        this.list = new BindingList<DocView>();
        this.list.ListChanged += list_ListChanged;
    }

    void list_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Total");
        OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private BindingList<DocView> list;

    public BindingList<DocView> List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set
        {
            list = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return list.Sum(x => x.Price); }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return list.Count; }
    }
}
```

**DocView:**

```
public class DocView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal price;

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

And here is a more concrete generic implementation of view model which let's you to use the same logic with different item types feeding custom Total and Count calculators:

```
public class GenericListViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Func<BindingList<T>, decimal> totalCalculator;    
        Func<BindingList<T>, int> countCalculator;

        public GenericListViewModel(Func<BindingList<T>, decimal> _totalCalculator, Func<BindingList<T>, int> _countCalculator)
        {
            this.list = new BindingList<T>();
            this.list.ListChanged += list_ListChanged;

            this.totalCalculator = _totalCalculator;
            this.countCalculator = _countCalculator;
        }

        void list_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Total");
            OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private BindingList<T> list;

        public BindingList<T> List
        {
            get { return list; }
            set
            {
                list = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("List");
            }
        }

        public decimal Total
        {
            get
            {
                if (totalCalculator != null)
                    return totalCalculator.Invoke(list);
                else
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Total Func must be impelmented");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                if (countCalculator != null)
                    return countCalculator.Invoke(list);
                else
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Count Func must be implemented");
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
public class MyDocViewModel: GenericListViewModel<DocView>
{
    public MyDocViewModel()
        : base(
        (list) =>
        {
            return list.Sum(x => x.Price);
        },
        (list) =>
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
        )
    {

    }
}
```